# WCF client caching responses?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service configured in a console application. This application allows me to enter different URLs and call a method of the WCF client. Every time I enter a URL I do set the binding because I'm using a proxy with credentials (username and password). When I enter the correct URL (username, password, URL and correct proxy port) I get a satisfactory result, but then when I enter a wrong one I get the same answer as before.

It seems that the responses are cached. I tried everything but nothing solves my problem.

My App Config:

```
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
  <proxy usesystemdefault="True" autoDetect="True"/>
</defaultProxy>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Default" useDefaultWebProxy="true" messageEncoding="Text" >
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="Windows" realm=""/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<client>
  <endpoint address="https://secured.planexware.com/wsdmsfe2/service.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Default" contract="ServiceReference.IDMSService"
    name="Default" />
</client>
```

The address format example is "`http:// user : pass @ proxyurl : port`" and this is my client factory class

```cs
    public static BasicHttpBinding DMSServiceClientFactory(string address)
    {
        try
        {
            return ConfigureClientWithProxy(address);    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private static BasicHttpBinding ConfigureClientWithProxy(string address)
    {
        // Tomo la configuracion del binding en el App.config
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding("Default");
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
        if (address.Contains("@"))
        {
            binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
            WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = GetWebProxyWithCredentials(address);
            binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Basic;
        }
        return binding;
    }

    private static WebProxy GetWebProxyWithCredentials(string address)
    {
        var partes = address.Split('@');
        var userPass = partes[0].Replace("http://", string.Empty);
        var urlPort = partes[1];

        string user = string.Empty;
        string pass = string.Empty;
        string url = string.Empty;
        string port = string.Empty;

        if (userPass.Contains(":"))
        {
            user = userPass.Split(':')[0];
            pass = userPass.Split(':')[1];
        }

        if (urlPort.Contains(":"))
        {
            url = urlPort.Split(':')[0];
            port = urlPort.Split(':')[1];
        }

        // La URL y las credenciales las sacamos de la especificacion que hizo el usuario al configurar el proxy
        WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy(string.Format(@"http://{0}:{1}", url, port));
        proxyObject.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);

        return proxyObject;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please update the question with client and server wcf configuration? Service Contract settings are important as well. It can happen, for example, if you are using PerSession instance model.

Comment: It's probably not caching the responses but rather the connection/session.